# Positive recurrent random walk on Z

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_n$, $n \geq 1$, be a random walk defined on $\mathbb{Z}$, where $X_i$, $ i \geq 1$, are i.i.d. bounded integers random variables. It is possible $S_n$ to be positive recurrent?

Comment: @nicomezi In this case, we get the Simple and Symmetric Random Walk, which is null recurrent. Am I wrong?Thanks!

Comment: You are totally correct. I just messed up. I think you have to force the walk to stay in some region.

Comment: I think you mean $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ (index with k)...  what have you tried here?  it should be immediate that these iid random variables need to be zero mean (e.g. using chernoff bounds).  If you consider what the steady state positive recurrent chain would tend to in terms of a distribution, vs what $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_n$ would tend to, you should get a contradiction by, say focusing on $Pr(S_n)=0$.

Comment: @user8675309. Thaks for you hint. Indeed we can use the Central Limit Theorem to get a contradiction with the existence of a invariant measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it was possible for the chain given by a sum of iid $X_k$ to be positive recurrent.  This is true in the trivial case of $X_k$ being constant (and zero) with probability 1, so assume $X_k$ takes on at least 2 values with positive probability each.

**1.)** It is should be immediate that $E[X_k]=0$ -- e.g. if instead the walk had negative drift, then for small $t\gt 0$

$P\big(S_n \gt 0\big) = P\big(t\cdot S_n \gt 0\big)=P\big(e^{t\cdot S_n} \gt 1\big)\leq E[e^{t\cdot S_n}] = E[e^{t\cdot X_1}]^k = M(t)^k= p^k$
for some $p\in(0,1)$, noting e.g. that by differentiating $M'(0) = \mu \lt 0$ and $M(0)= 1$, so for $t$ small enough $0\lt M(t)\lt 1$.

hence the expected number of visits to the positive integers is finite (geometric series). And thus the steady state probability of visiting positive integers is zero which implies $X_k$ takes on strictly non-positive values and the chain is transient. (For the case of positive drift, rerun the argument on $S_n^* := -S_n$)

Alternative justifications: You can also do this with SLLN or adapt the below CLT argument to the case of non-zero drift.

**2.)**  Since the chain is positive recurrent, we have, for any $m\gt 0$
$P\big(S_n \gt m\big) \rightarrow c$ for some $c\in \big(0,1\big)$ and as $m\to \infty$, $c\to 0$
this implies
$P\big(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \gt m\big) \rightarrow 0$

but by Central Limit Theorem
$\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to N\big(0,\sigma^2\big)$ hence
$P\big(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \gt m\big) \rightarrow c'$   for $c'\in \big(0,1\big)$
which is a contradiction.

**addendum**
for a slightly different finish with a few more details spelled out, consider that since the chain starts at state 0 and by assumption it is positive recurrent, it suffices to tease out a contradiction with $P\big(S_n =0\big)$.

By positive recurrence assumption $P\big(S_n = 0\big)\to \pi_0 \in (0,1)$, or $\big \vert P\big(S_n = 0\big) - \pi_0\big \vert \lt \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ for $n\geq n^*$.

And we also have
$0\leq P\big(S_n = 0\big) = P\big(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = 0\big) \lt \epsilon'$
for $n\geq n'$ by CLT (and e.g. using Stein's Method or Berry-Essen for explicit error bounds).

Now select $\epsilon: =\epsilon' := \frac{\pi_0}{3} $ and $m:=\max\big(n',n^*\big)$ and we get

$\frac{2}{3}\pi_0 \lt \Big \vert \big \vert\pi_0\big \vert- \big \vert P\big(\frac{S_{m}}{\sqrt{m}} = 0\big)\big \vert  \Big \vert \leq \Big \vert \pi_0- P\big(\frac{S_{m}}{\sqrt{m}} = 0\big)  \Big \vert=\big \vert P\big(S_{m} = 0\big) - \pi_0\big \vert  \lt \epsilon = \frac{1}{3}\pi_0$
which is a contradiction